# Is it possible to generate a report that will show who has full permission to other user mailboxes in Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010

Question says it all: I'd like to generate a report that will show a complete list of who has access to other user mailboxes.

PowerShell is preferred but I'll use Exchange Tools as well if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mind adding the exact command as an answer? I'm not quite grasping where I should insert that into the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | ? {($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -And ($_.User.ToString() -ne 'NT AUTHORITY\SELF') -And ($_.Deny -eq $false)}
```

Comment: This has some extra fields in it as well but it definitely gives me the exact details I'm looking for. Thanks for your help!